# Pushing to multiple remotes with different proxies with single command for each branch

Tags: git, azure, proxy, gitlab

I want for each branch do `git push` and it will push to my 2 remotes (each branch has different remotes).

I did try this for each branch:

```
git remote set-url --add --push all repo1
git remote set-url --add --push all repo2
git branch --set-upstream-to=all/master
```

This should work, but I have problem with proxy. `repo1` is in my GitLab repo in intranet and does not use proxy, but `repo2` is in Azure and needs proxy. Therefore the `git push` fails.

How to get this working with different proxies for urls in the same remote? Or maybe some other ideas how to tackle this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to write 2 batch files one for setting the proxy and one for unsetting the proxy and manage it.

You can set the Git proxy using the below command in the git bash. Set for both HTTP and HTTPS proxy.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxy.server.com:8080
git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@proxy.server.com:8080

//Replace username with your proxy username
//Replace password with your proxy password
//Replace proxy.server.com with the proxy domain URL.
//Replace 8080 with the proxy port no configured on the proxy server.
```

To Unset the Git Proxy use the below commands

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Checkout my blog on  [How to configure Git proxy](https://itsmycode.com/configure-git-proxy/) and [How to unset the Git Proxy](https://itsmycode.com/configure-git-proxy/) for more details